# How can I update values of a dropdown list with angular?

Tags: mysql, angular, spring-boot, frontend, dropdown

I want to update values into dropdown list but when I click in the form the value change to null.
knowing that the add works correctly . Anyone can help me please ?
this is my html code:

```
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="service">Service</label>
       <select id="service" class="form-control" ngModel="{{editPersonne?.service}}" name="serviceId">
            <option value="">Service</option>
      <option value="service.id" *ngFor="let service of services" >{{service.designation}}</option>
        </select>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use varibale

```html
<div class="form-group">
   <label for="service">Service</label>
     <select id="service" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="{{editPersonne?.service}}" name="serviceId">
        <option value="">Service</option>
        <option [value]="service.id" *ngFor="let service of services" >{{service.designation}}</option>
     </select>
</div>
```

or

```html
<div class="form-group">
   <label for="service">Service</label>
     <select id="service" class="form-control" ngModel="{{editPersonne?.service}}" name="serviceId">
        <option value="">Service</option>
        <option value="{{service.id}}" *ngFor="let service of services" >{{service.designation}}</option>
     </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Check ngModel variable